# How can we declare lvalue inplace while calling a function with lvalue reference parameter?

Tags: c++

If I have a function like this:

```
int calc(const DataVec& data_vec, int& sub_sum);
```

how can I call that without a explicit lvalue definition of type int?

```
auto calc_result = calc(data_vec, int()); // error, int() is not a lvalue
```

Below is a valid form:

```
int _;  // not interested
auto calc_result = calc(data_vec, _);
```

Comment: If the function is written like this (without any additional overloads for rvalue arguments), then it is not intended that you can call it with a temporary. So either there is a good reason that you _shouldn't_ try to do that or the interface offered by `calc` is wrong and there should be another overload taking e.g. a `const int&` or `int&&`.

Comment: You cannot. Having the function update a temporary is a bug 99% of the time, so just not allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be solved with function overloading. Like

```
int calc(const DataVec& data_vec);
```

Your overloaded function could be a simple wrapper around your dummy-int variable workaround:

```
int calc(const DataVec& data_vec)
{
    int dummy = 0;
    return calc(data_vec, dummy);
}
```

Please note that this might be a suitable workaround to the problem. But it might as well be a workaround for a problem that doesn't really exist, and and there shouldn't really *be* any workarounds. Perhaps there is a very good reason for the original `calc` functions second argument being a non-const lvalue reference?

Comment: It might as well just look like a workaround when in reality it does create the problem. If thats not the case the original `calc` should be fixed perhaps